# How hide Show Entities drop down and search box in DataTable when export to Excel sheet

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

I am using jquery DataTable in MVC project to create a Grid. This is the the link of what I have used:

https://www.datatables.net/

I have added the functionality to Export the Grid to Excel. This is the code:

```
  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
e.preventDefault();
```

and this is my DataTable in my view page:

```
 var $table = $('#DataLegal');

// Get a reference to all of our columns by the TH tag
var $columns = $('thead th', $table);

// Create our DataTable
var table = $table.DataTable({
    "sort": true

});
```

Show entries and Search box is part of DataTable. When I export to Excel here are visible in Excel sheet How I can hide them and not show in Excel sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the Export options that come standard with JQuery DataTables. It has styling, column options, and you can export to excel, pdf, csv, etc. [Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) is an example.